# Do I need to implement a b-tree search for this?

Tags: algorithm, math, search, b-tree

I have an array of integers, which could run into the hundreds of thousands (or more), sorted numerically ascending since that's how they were originally stacked.

I need to be able to query the array to get the index of its first occurrence of a number `>=` some input, as efficiently as possible.  The only way I would know how to do this without even thinking about it would be to iterate through the array testing the condition until it returns true, at which point I'd stop iterating.  However, this is the most expensive solution to this problem and I'm looking for the best algorithm to solve it.

I'm coding in Objective-C, but I'll give an example in JavaScript to broaden the audience of people who are able to respond.

```
// Sample set
var numbers = [1, 7, 23, 23, 23, 89, 1002, 1003];

var indexAfter100 = getIndexOfValueGreaterThan(100);
var indexAfter7 = getIndexOfValueGreaterThan(7);

// (indexAfter100 == 6) == true
// (indexAfter7 == 2) == true
```

Putting this data into a DB in order to perform this search will only be a last-resort solution since I'm keen to see some sort of algorithm to tackle this quickly in memory.

I *do* have the ability to change the data structure, or to store an additional data structure as I'm building the array, since my program has already pushed each number one by one onto this stack, so I'd just modify the code that's adding them to the stack.  Searching for the index as they're being added to the stack isn't possible since the search operation will be repeated frequently with different values after the fact.

Right now I'm thinking "B-Tree" but to be honest, I would have no idea how to implement one and before I go off and start figuring that out, I wonder if there's a nice algorithm that fits this single use-case better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Objective C could even have a built-in method for that (many languages I know do). B-tree won't probably help much, unless you want to store the data on disk.

Comment: Thank you.  Reading this now.

Comment: That's so simple and is exactly the sort of algorithm I was looking for, thank you.  Now I'm just kicking myself that this did not pop into my own head several hours ago! :P

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Objective-C, but C (plain 'ol C) comes with a function called `bsearch` (besides, AFAIK, Obj-C can call C functions just fine):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/

That basically does a binary search which sounds like it's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A fast search algorithm should be able to handle an array of ints of that size without taking too long, I should think (and the array is sorted, so a binary search would probably be the way to go).

I think a btree is probably overkill...

Answer (score 0):

Since they are sorted in a particular ASCending order and you only need the bigger ones, I would serialize that array, explode it by the INT and keep the part of the serialized string that holds the bigger INTs, then unserialize it and voilá.

Answer (score 0):

Linear search also referred to as sequential search looks at each element in sequence from the start to see if the desired element is present in the data structure. When the amount of data is small, this search is fast.Its easy but work needed is in proportion to the amount of data to be searched.Doubling the number of elements will double the time to search if the desired element is not present.

Binary search is efficient for larger array. In this we check the middle element.If the value is bigger that what we are looking for, then look in the first half;otherwise,look in the second half. Repeat this until the desired item is found. The table must be sorted for binary search. It eliminates half the data at each iteration.Its logarithmic